# What are the implications of "strain on the memory controller"?

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-building, microcontroller

Numerous articles and postings advise using as few memory sticks as possible, and/or using registered memory for configurations with many sticks, citing "strain on the memory controller".

I am unclear on what exactly this means and whether I should care? If my memory controller is strained, will it physically "burn out" faster? Will my computer be less stable or slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer will be less stable and/or slower. If you aren't using registered or buffered memory, the memory controller has to drive the address pins on every chip on every memory stick. The more loads a source has to drive, the longer it will take that source to establish a clear signal that can be reliably detected. This means a reduction in speed, reliability, or both.

Each memory channel has its own drivers. So if you have a dual-channel system, you can drive twice as many chips with the same number of loads per driver. With a quad-channel system, four times as many.

Registered and buffered memory has drivers on each memory stick. This means the memory controller only has to drive one input per stick of memory instead of one input per memory chip. But registered/buffered memory adds a bit of delay as the memory controller has to drive the buffer and then the buffer produces outputs for each memory chip on that stick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. do you by any chance have data to support this? Like, are there actually measurably more crashes when there are two sticks per channel vs one?

Comment: @Thoughtcraft Definitely. You can empirically demonstrate this very easily. Just clock your memory as aggressively as it will go and then switch the sticks so they're both on the same channel instead of on different channels. The machine will fail memory tests almost every time.